# How do I 'remove' a redundant repository

Tags: ppa, repository

I have a ppa 'installed' which has many packages which have been installed (replacing packages installed from Ubuntu standard repos) on my Ubuntu Trusty PC. I want to no longer use that ppa and want to now use the same packages from Ubuntu standard repos. If I purge it (e.g. using Y PPA Manager), I presume that will result in the removal of these packages. Would it automatically replace them with the ones from the Ubuntu standard repos. If not, how do I do this?
PS I have Synaptic installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `ppa-purge` will replace all the packages from that ppa with the most current default packages from the Ubuntu repos.

The "Y PPA Manager" just makes it easy to find the ppa as you don't have to try to type the name into the command line, it still calls `ppa-purge` while running.

Be PATIENT while running the program, it can take a while to complete each step.  While each step is running, it will seem like the purge is frozen.  DO NOT kill the program or shut your computer down while it is running, while it should still be possible to fix after a partial purge, it will be a major headache and is best avoided.  For a large ppa, the time to complete could be 10+ minutes.  Longer if you have a slow internet connection, as all the packages will have to be downloaded.

As to the title of your question "How do I"  I would recommend the "Y PPA Manager"  other wise you will need to type `ppa-purge ppa:{name of ppa here} so you must know the *exact* name to do it by terminal.  Y PPA will just take care of it for you.